# 標準ライブラリが入り混じったコードの意味が知りたい

Tags: c++

以下のコードが何をしてるのか分かりましたら具体的に教えて下さい。

`std::sheard_ptr<std::vector<std::sheard_ptr<RxInfos>>> rxinfo;`

Comment: 化けているみたいstd::sheard_ptr>> rxinfo;ではなくstd::sheard_ptr<std::vector<std::sheard_ptr<RxpkInfo>>> rxp;です。

Comment: 質問にクローズ票を投じます。オフトピックである理由: 本家にて質問されるべき投稿です。

Comment: @YukiInoue 本家に migrate することは可能でしょうか？

Comment: @nekketsuuu migrate のボタンが、ぱっと見だ感じ存在していないです。もしかしたら、 migrate 機能は今オフになっているのかもしれない、と思っています。

Comment: @here 移動、できました。自分が機能をしらないだけでした。 (すいません)

Comment: `sheard_ptr` は `shared_ptr` ではないですかね。

Answer (score 1):

「何をしているか」については「変数」を用意しているだけですが、
こういった、込み入った型は、typedefかusingを使って
分解してみるとわかりやすいかもしれません。自分はたいていそうしてます。

```
//std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<RxInfos>>> rxinfo;　を分解すると・・
using   RxInfos_Ptr = std::shared_ptr<RxInfos>;
using   RxInfos_Ptr_Vct = std::vector<RxInfos_Ptr>;
using   RxInfos_Ptr_Vct_Ptr = std::shared_ptr< RxInfos_Ptr_Vct>;
RxInfos_Ptr_Vct_Ptr rxinfo;//最終的にはこれ
```

Answer (score 0):

[cpprefjp](https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/memory/shared_ptr.html) から `std::shared_ptr` の解説を引用します。

> `shared_ptr` は、指定されたリソースへの所有権(ownership)を共有(share)するスマートポインタである。

このもとで、ご提示のソースは「`RxInfo` への `shared_ptr` のベクターへの `shared_ptr`」を宣言しています (`RxInfos` が具体的に何なのかは知りませんが……)。